# Retrieving sublayers in Core Animation

Tags: xcode, core-animation

I am currently developing a small application with Core Animation to get some knowledge about how the framework works.
Now I was wondering how I'd be able to perform transformations dynamically on a specific sublayer. I had thought it would be as simple as `[somelayer sublayers][0].transform = CATransform3DMake.........;`, but it turned out that was not the case.
So my question is: How can I alter sublayers within the Core Animation Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant `[[somelayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0].transform = CATransform3DMake ...`?

Comment: Ouch, yes that's what I was looking for.
I had completely overlooked "objectAtIndex:".
Thank you!